# declare variables in argument list

Tags: c#, declare

It's possible in c# 7 to declare variables for `out` variables in argument list:

```
if (int.TryParse(input, out int result))
    WriteLine(result);
```

Is it possible to declare ("non out") variable in argument list? Like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(string result=FuncGetStr()))
        WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: @m.rogalski I have tried, it doesn't work, but may be I'm wrong in syntax and there is a possibility?

Comment: May be it is more useful to look in the c# 7 changes notes instead of asking such a question?

Comment: The ability to declare `out` variables inline arises from the awkwardness that it a) has to be a variable rather than a value and b) there's often nothing too useful to do with the value if you declare it before the function is called. I don't see the same *motivations* for other such uses.

Comment: I don't think it's possible and you proved it.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Of course I have looked to the specification and have not found declaring of "non out" variables in args list, but can be that I have not found! If you don't find something, means not it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in the argument list, no.

You *could* use pattern matching for this, but I wouldn't advise it:

```
if (FuncGetStr() is string result && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
```

That keeps the declaration within the source code of the `if`, but the scope of `result` is still the enclosing block, so I think it would much simpler just to separate out:

```
// Mostly equivalent, and easier to read
string result = FuncGetStr();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
{
    ...
}
```

There are two differences I can think of:

- `result` isn't definitely assigned after the `if` statement in the first version
- `string.IsNullOrEmpty` isn't even called in the first version if `FuncGetStr()` returns null, as the `is` pattern won't match. You *could* therefore write it as:

  ```
  if (FuncGetStr() is string result && result != "")
  ```

---

To be utterly horrible, you *could* do it, with a helper method to let you use `out` parameters. Here's a complete example. Please note that I am *not* suggesting this as something to do.

```
// EVIL CODE: DO NOT USE
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Call(FuncGetStr, out string result)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }

    static string FuncGetStr() => "foo";

    static T Call<T>(Func<T> func, out T x) => x = func();
}
```

Comment: You are right with "Mostly equivalent". I have thought to make it shorter ;) "easier to read" - opinion based ;)

Comment: @Rekshino: While readability is subjective to an extent, I doubt that there are many C# developers who would genuinely find the first form simpler to read. Oh, and there's a second difference I hadn't mentioned - the first form doesn't call `string.IsNullOrEmpty` if `FuncGetStr()` returns null. (Edited.) I would definitely suggest that it's worth acknowledging that "shorter" and "more readable" can be very, very different.

Comment: Fully agree that ' "shorter" and "more readable" can be very, very differen '

Comment: @Rekshino: I've added a horrible piece of code at the bottom, to let you use `out` parameters. Obviously you shouldn't actually do this.

Comment: "utterly horrible"! :)) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can *assign* variables in statements, but the *declaration* of the variables should be done outside of them. You can't combine them (outside `out` and pattern matching, as you already indicated in your question).

```
bool b;
string a;

if (b = string.IsNullOrEmpty(a = "a")){ }
```

On the *why* this behavior is different than with `out`, etc, [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever)'s comment might be interesting:

> The ability to declare `out` variables inline arises from the awkwardness that it a) has to be a variable rather than a value and b) there's often nothing too useful to do with the value if you declare it before the function is called. I don't see the same motivations for other such uses.

Comment: "You can't combine them" - well, except for pattern matching and out variables...

Comment: Yes, but that means that your answer seems to contradict the question, because you haven't put any kind of restriction on your statement.

Comment: Ah, okay. Clarified.